# Sending a list of dictionaries to a udp socket in python 3

Tags: python, list, sockets, dictionary, udp

i would like to send a list of dictionaries through a udp socket. But i get the error of: **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'**
How can i send it?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: You can `pickle.dumps(..)` them.

Comment: Can you explain this more, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library like `pickle` that converts an object into a binary stream. For instance:

```
import pickle

pickle.dumps(["Hello","World"])
```

This produces:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(["Hello","World"])
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x00Worldq\x02e.'
```

At the receiving end, you can then use `pickle.loads(..)` to reconstruct the list:

```
>>> pickle.loads(b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x00Worldq\x02e.')
['Hello', 'World']
```

Note however that **UDP send a datagram**. So the content needs to fit in the maximum **size of a datagram**.

Comment: Thank you! But now i get the error from the server side: **EOF Error: Ran out of input** Do you know what it means?

Comment: @user8097385: are you sure that you received the data, that is a typical error **if an empty packet is received**.

Comment: I am sure, because i am the one sending the data... And i also printed to checked if it exists, and it did...

Comment: @user8097385: is it possible you exhausted the UDP package (reader) by printing the content. Can you edit your question with the sending and receiving code (or at least a mwe part)?